# Cognito error AccessDenied with credentials obtained from cognito identity pool (Javascript AWS SDK, region cn-north-1)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-nodejs

I've been trying to get Cognito to work for more than a day now.

Our scenario that I want to get to work is the "Authenticate with a Third Party and Access AWS Services with an Identity Pool" one on [this page (https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-scenarios.html)](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-scenarios.html)

Currently I generate credentials with `AWS.EnvironmentCredentials`, create a new `CognitoIdentity` and use that to call `getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity` in our backend.

```
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.EnvironmentCredentials(...);
AWS.config.update({region: 'cn-north-1'});
const cognitoidentity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity({apiVersion: '2014-06-30'});

const params = {
  IdentityPoolId: 'cn-north-1:XXXXXX',
  Logins: {
    '<DeveloperProviderName>': identifierStr,
  },
};
```

This works fine an I can receive the neccecary `token` and `identityId` that I return to my front end. There I exchange the `token` and `identityId` for credentials.

```
AWS.config.region = 'cn-north-1';
const cognitoidentity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity({apiVersion: '2014-06-30'});
const params = {
  IdentityId: identityId,
  Logins: {
    'cognito-identity.cn-north-1.amazonaws.com.cn': token, //using the key for cn-north-1
  }
};

cognitoidentity.getCredentialsForIdentity(params, (err, data) => {
  if (err){
    //handle error
  } else { 
    //get credentials
    //using AccessKeyId and SecretKey and SessionToken to use AWS services
  }
});
```

Here I'll get the error `InvalidAccessKeyId: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.`

**Why do I get this error? And how do I resolve it?**

I was thinking that I might need to change the credentials configuration for the backend, as the sample code in the identity pool suggests, but this gives the error `Missing credentials in config` on the server.

```
// Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider
AWS.config.region = 'cn-north-1'; // Region
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
  IdentityPoolId: 'cn-north-1:XXXXXXX',
});
```

---

**edit**: After some research I added `SessionToken` to the configurations (additional to AccessKey and SecretKey), but get a new error `AccessDenied` now. I checked in my role configurations and I have assigned the correct rights to my authenticated role, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my second error as well.

I was missing a correct bucket policy (since I am trying to access S3). The bucket policy needs to be updated with

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy01",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement01",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": <IdentityPoolAuthenticatedRole>
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws-cn:s3:::<bucketName>/*" // <* or specified keyName>
        },
        ...
        // more statements
    ]
}
```

so the bucket knows requests from  are okay, as far as I understand.

---

This [blog post](https://medium.com/@haydnjmorris/uploading-photos-to-aws-s3-getting-started-with-cognito-and-iam-c96ba5b5496d) helped me to get on the right track, but it assumes you're setting up for unauthorized users and not using Identity Pools.